# How to access the variable decleared inside of private class from other classes in java?

Tags: java, class, private

I have login page with 2 text field and a login button. when login button is clicked, the username and password is retrieved from txtfield and check with username and password in database. if password and username is correct, it goes to main page. I was to get the username and show the name in main page. But all the code to check with database and retrive the data from database is inside the private class of buttonActionPerformed. Eventhough i retrive the username from database and store in variable, I can't access it from other class as it is private class. So what shall i do to access the variable which i declear inside the private class. I tried to declear variable outside the private class and update it inside the private class but still i get blank when i call from other class.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your classes and the variable?

Comment: are you talking about private **class** or fields? is your private **class** inner/nested class?

Comment: I tried to put the code but not allowed to put here. I am talking about private class. When i double click the button on jframe, this private class is created to perform the code when actionperformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PrivateInformationRetreiving{
private int PrivateInfo;
public void setPrivateInfo(int PrivateInfo)
{
this.PrivateInfo=PrivateInfo;
}
public int getPrivateInfo(){return PrivateInfo;}
}
```

---

## Explanation

First, the variable `PrivateInfo` is declared `private`, it means only the methods inside the class `PrivateInformationRetreiving` will know about `PrivateInfo`.
So, when we want to know about the private variable`PrivateInfo`, we must do it with `public` methods.
`public` elements are accessible not only in the class, but also outside the class.
So, `setPrivateInfo()` can access `PrivateInfo` as it is inside the class.
So, we have to use the mathods, `setPrivateInfo()` and `getPrivateInfo()` as interfaces to access`PrivateInfo`.

Comment: Can you Explain this please as i am beginner, i didnt understand this.

Comment: I will add the explanation in my answer

Comment: shall i put this codes inside the private class or somewhere else?

Comment: @user2068452 sure  why are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

> So what shall i do to access the variable which i declear inside the private class. I tried to declear variable outside the private class and update it inside the private class but still i get blank when i call from other class.

The Reflection API is used to access private variables. If you had a class called Database and the private field in it was defPU, you would access it (and set it null) as follows:

```
Field defPUField = Database.class.getDeclaredField("defPU");
defPUField.setAccessible(true);
Field modsField = Field.class. .getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modsField.setAccessible(true);
modsField.setInt(defPUField, 10);
defPUField.set(null, testVal);
```

I'd recommend you just use [dp4j](http://dp4j.com) to generate that Reflection code for you, behind the scenes:

```
@com.dp4j.TestPrivates
void aMethod(){
 Database.defPU = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing a successful log in just put the user data to the session and then redirect. You won't have to create another request to the database when you need the currently logged on user's name, so it's faster and more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

if you are declaring it as private, you CANNOT access it outside the class context.

An option would be to expose public getters/setters to interact with your variable.

```
public class MyClass {
    private int x;
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int value){
        x = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cannot" is a strong word.

Comment: are you saying that it is incorrect? If so please provide example.

Comment: where do you want me to put these code, inside the private class or just by itself??

Comment: You can access private fields via multiple mechanisms, including reflection and native code. Usually you should not -- a private field is *intended* to be accessed only within the enclosing top-level class.